# I get "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed" with open_uri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, docker

I am getting an error saying "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed" when I give an argument to my Docker image in running.

My application source code follows:

```rb
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

crawling_url = ARGV[0]

unless crawling_url
  puts "URL to crawl is empty"
  exit 1
end

puts crawling_url
page = Nokogiri.HTML(open(crawling_url))

puts page.title
```

And Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ruby:2.6

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

CMD ["ruby", "/usr/src/app/crawler.rb"]
```

The build command I use is:

```sh
$ docker build -t crawler .
```

When I don't give any argument to my script, it works, but when I give one, it doesn't.

```sh
$ docker run -it crawler
URL to crawl is empty

$ docker run -it crawler "https://google.com"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"https://google.com\": stat https://google.com: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I changed `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` at last.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "/usr/src/app/crawler.rb"]
```